# ruby find the index of the next available number

Tags: ruby

I have a `find_num` method that returns the index of a specified number in an ordered array, e.g.

```
find_num(6, [1, 4, 6, 9, 13]) #=> 2
```

however my spec also requires that if the number is not available it finds the position of the next highest number so ...

```
find_num(8, [1, 4, 6, 9, 13]) #=> 3
```

as 9 is the next available number.

Having trouble implementing this... I have thought of iterating through the whole array but I am told to take into account the array could be large...

Comment: You might want to show your implementation for the first part.

Comment: I just realised my first part iterates through! Doh!

Answer (score 6):

You can pass a block to [`index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-index) and it ...

> [...] returns the *index* of the first object for which the block returns `true`. Returns `nil` if no match is found.

Examples:

```
[1, 4, 6, 9, 13].index { |n| n >= 6 }  #=> 2
[1, 4, 6, 9, 13].index { |n| n >= 8 }  #=> 3
[1, 4, 6, 9, 13].index { |n| n >= 15 } #=> nil
```

Because this requires the array to be ordered, you can also use [`bsearch_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-bsearch_index) which performs a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Comment: I think he wanted one function that would do both at the same time (compare equality and if no equality found then get the first number strictly superior). Your solution '[1, 4, 6, 9, 8, 13].index { |n| n >= 8 }' will return 3 when it should return 4.

Comment: @Pholochtairze the array must be ordered, I've updated my answer. However, the OP did not specify the kind of order, "next available" doesn't necessarily mean "next higher" ... maybe some clarification is needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can also find a index of any element in array like this.

```
  2.1.8 :040 > [1, 4, 6, 9, 13].index(6)
 => 2
  2.1.8 :041 > [1, 4, 6, 9, 13].index(15)
 => nil
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_num(n,a)
  a.each_with_index.to_a.sort_by(&:first).find { |nbr,_| nbr >= n }.last 
end

find_num(6, [1, 4, 6, 9, 13])
  #=> 2 
find_num(8, [1, 4, 6, 9, 13]) #=> 3
  #=> 3
```

The steps for

```
n = 8
a =  [1, 4, 6, 9, 13]
```

are as follows.

```
b = a.each_with_index.to_a
  #=> [[1, 0], [4, 1], [6, 2], [9, 3], [13, 4]] 
c = b.sort_by(&:first)
  #=> [[1, 0], [4, 1], [6, 2], [9, 3], [13, 4]] 
d = c.find { |nbr,_| nbr >= n }
  #=> [9, 3] 
d.last 
  #=> 3
```